# Как перезаписать значения с одного файла в другой при определенном условии?

Tags: python, scripts

У меня задача:

Есть файл, в котором на строку есть 2 текстовых значения. Значения разделены пробелом
Вот пример данных:

```
90.01 2e-06
90.02 4e-06
90.03 6e-06
90.04 8e-06
90.05 1e-05
90.06 1.2e-05
90.07 1.4e-05
90.08 1.6e-05
90.09 1.7e-05
90.1 1.9e-05
90.11 2.1e-05
90.12 2.3e-05
90.13 2.5e-05
90.14 2.7e-05
90.15 2.9e-05
90.16 3.1e-05
90.17 3.3e-05
90.18 3.5e-05
90.19 3.7e-05
90.2 3.9e-05
90.21 4.1e-05
90.22 4.3e-05
90.23 4.5e-05
```

Я хочу пройтись по файлу и суммировать значения во второй колонке.
Как только сумма этих значений, превышает определенное значение, я хочу записать в другой файл значение из колонки 1, на котором произошло это превышение и начать процесс опять.

Т. е. во втором файле должно быть что-то вроде:

```
90.1
90.5
91.0
91.5
```

Делаю это так:

```
with open('long_1.txt', 'a+') as k:
    with open('long.txt', 'r') as f:
        summa = 0
        for i in f:
            s = i.split()
            s = float(s[1])
            summa +=s
            if summa >1:
                k.write(str(s[0]) + '\n')
                summa = 0
```

Но, второй файл у меня почему-то пустой.
Где я сделал ошибку и как правильно решить задачу? 
Я могу решить задачу с посмошью списков и массивов, но этот вериант не подходит)

Спасибо)

Comment: Сумма даже всех значений из второго столбца не превышает `1`.

Comment: это пример. Сам исходник содержит миллионы строк

Comment: Видимо, даже сумма этого миллиона не превышает `1`. Вас, кстати, не смущает, что Ваш код даже не запускается?

Comment: Если заменить условие на `> 0.0001`, то записи в новом файле появляются, алгоритм верный, не считая "косяка" в строках `s = float(s[1]); summa +=s`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Во-первых, Ваш код не отработает, потому что Вы в `s` записываете какой-то `float`, а затем пытаетесь обратиться к `[0]` элементу этого `float`'а. Исправленный код:

```py
with open('long_1.txt', 'a+') as k:
    with open('long.txt', 'r') as f:
        summa = 0
        for i in f:
            s = i.split()
            summa += float(s[1])
            if summa >1:
                k.write(str(s[0]) + '\n')
                summa = 0
```

- Во-вторых, алгоритм написан верно. Просто не выполняется условие `> 1`. Если поставить условие `> 0.0001`, то новые записи появляться будут.

  ---

  Мне захотелось немного отрефакторить Ваш код:

```py
with open("long.txt", "r") as ifp, open("long_1.txt", "w") as ofp:
    current_sum = 0
    for ifp_line in ifp:
        lhs, rhs = ifp_line.split()
        current_sum += float(rhs)
        if current_sum > 1:
            ofp.write(lhs + "\n")
            current_sum = 0
```

Comment: да, спасибо, вы правы. увидел ошибку

Answer (score 3):

В `context manager` можно открывать несколько файлов - нет необходимости использовать вложения:

```
with open('long_1.txt', 'a+') as fout, open('long.txt', 'r') as fin:
    sum_ = 0
    for line in fin:
        v1, v2 = line.split()
        sum_ += float(v2)
        if sum_ > 1:
            print(f"{v1}", file=fout)
            sum_ = 0
```